# Remove spaces in words

Tags: sql, parsing, postgresql, text-parsing

I do have a lot of strings in my database (PostgreSQL), an example:

```
with mystrings as (
    select 'H e l l o, how are you'::varchar string union all
    select 'I am fine, t h a n k you'::varchar string union all
    select 'This is s t r a n g e text'::varchar string union all
    select 'With c r a z y space b e t w e e n characters'::varchar string 
)
select * from mystrings
```

Is there a way how I can remove spaces between characters in words? For my example the result should be:

```
Hello, how are you
I am fine, thank you
This is strange text
With crazy space between characters
```

I started with `replace`, but there are many such words with spaces between characters and I cannot even find them all.

Because it might be difficult to meaningfully concatenate characters, it might be better idea to get just list of concatenation candidates. Using example data, the result should be:

```
H e l l o
t h a n k
s t r a n g e
c r a z y
b e t w e e n
```

Such query should find and return all substrings in string when there are at least three individual characters separated by two spaces (and continue until patern `[space] individual character` occurs):

```
He l l o how are you --> llo
H e l l o how are you --> Hello
C r a z y space b e t w e e n --> {crazy, between}
```

Comment: . . Is it always one space?  Do you have a table of allowable words?

Comment: For the cases I have found there is always one space. There is English dictionary installed for full search support in PostgreSQL. Not sure whether I can use this as a list of allowable words.

Comment: Even with the use of a dictionary, this is hopelessly ambiguous. Many words can be concatenated.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I have updated my question - given it's "hopelessly ambiguous" it might be better idea to get list of concatenation candidates only.

Comment: @twn08 hope my answer helps (gets your concatenation candidates )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your ***edited*** question, the below gets all the possible candidates that have a `least three individual characters separated by two spaces`

```
SELECT 
    data || ' --> {' || replace_candidates || '}'
FROM(
SELECT 
    data,
    ( SELECT 
            array_to_string( array_agg( data ),',' )  
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                data,
                length( data ) 
            FROM ( 
                SELECT 
                    replace( data, ' ', '' ) AS data 
                FROM 
                    regexp_split_to_table( data, '\S{2,}' ) AS data 
                ) t
            WHERE length( data ) > 2
        ) t ) AS replace_candidates
    FROM
        mystrings
) T
WHERE 
  replace_candidates IS NOT NULL
```

**Working**

Start looking at the inner most query first (the one with `regexp_split_to_table`)

1. The `regexg` gets all strings that have `2 characters in a sequence` (not `separated` by a space)
2. `regexp_split_to_table` gets the inverse of the match, more on it [**here**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)
3. Replace spaces by a `empty char` and filter `records` having a `length greater than 2`

The reaming are `array aggregate` functions to take care of `formatting`, as per your requirement, more of this [**here**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-aggregate.html)

**Results**

```
H e l l o how are you --> {Hello}
I am fine, t h a n k you --> {thank}
This is s t r a n g e text --> {strange}
With c r a z y space b e t w e e n characters --> {crazy,between}
SOME MORE TEST T E X T --> {TEXT}
```

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/5c038/5)

**Note:** It considers chars which fall in as `[space][char][space]`, but, you can modify it to suit your needs as `[space][space][char][space]` or `[space][char][special_char][space]` ...

Hope this helps ;p

Answer (score 0):

You can use a resource such as online dictionary if the word exists then you dont have to remove spaces otherwise remove spaces or you can use a table where you have to put all strings that exist and  then you have to check with that table.Hope you got my point.

Comment: I'm not sure this will help - there is a lot of words with one or two characters. I think I have to remove somehow spaces first and then probably match against dictionary.

Comment: Right! as 'a' can be a single article or it can be part of a word.

Answer (score 0):

The following finds possible concatenation candidates:

```
 with mystrings as (
    select 'H e l l o, how are you'::varchar string union all
    select 'I am fine, t h a n k you'::varchar string union all
    select 'This is s t r a n g e text'::varchar string union all
    select 'With c r a z y space b e t w e e n characters'::varchar string 
)

, u as (
select string, strpart[rn] as strpart, rn
from  (
   select *, generate_subscripts(strpart, 1) as rn
   from  (
      select string, string_to_array(replace(string,',',''), ' ') as strpart
      from   mystrings
      ) x
   ) y
)

,w as (
select 
   string,strpart,rn, 
   case when length(strpart) = 1 then 1 else 0 end as indchar ,
   case when coalesce(length(lag(strpart) over()),0) <> 1 and length(strpart) = 1 then 1 else 0 end as strstart,
   case when coalesce(length(lead(strpart) over()),0) <> 1 and length(strpart) = 1 then 1 else 0 end as strend   
from u
) 


,x as (
   select 
      string,rn,strpart,indchar,strstart,
      sum(strstart) over (order by string, rn) as strid 
   from w 
   where indchar = 1 and not (strstart = 1 and strend = 1)
    )

select string, array_to_string(array_agg(strpart),'') as candidate from x group by string, strid
```